# Database of funded US Department of Defense (DoD) component grant proposals with abstracts: Does it exist?

Tags: funding, united-states

I'm looking for a database of funded grant proposals with abstracts for various DoD components (e.g., DARPA, AFRL, etc.), similar to the one for the [NSF](http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/).

The [Federal Business Opportunities (a.k.a. FedBizOpps)](https://www.fbo.gov) website exists, but it doesn't list the abstracts, the information it does give is not really useful, and the search capabilities on that site are kind of clunky.

Does such a database of funded grant proposals with abstracts for
US DoD components exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most DoD contracts, there is no database or similar system that allows you to get any sort of abstract.  I know this because our research librarians, who track this sort of thing and are quite good at their jobs, have told me definitively that this is the case.

If you really want information about specific projects, you could file a [FOIA request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_Information_Act_(United_States)), using something like the USA Spending site referenced in Aleksandr Blekh's post.  Note, however, that the intricacies of DoD contracting mean that it may be rather difficult to actually tell which contracts are associated with which programs: for example, many DARPA contracts are actually not concluded by DARPA, but by other DoD organizations acting on their behalf.  [FFRDCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federally_funded_research_and_development_centers) and other sorts of special cases further complicate matters.

Answer (score 3):

You can search https://dodgrantawards.dtic.mil/grants/#/home and find DoD awards from 2014 to current.

"This website contains publicly-searchable descriptive abstracts of DoD grant awards from December 9, 2014 (the date of passage of the Act), along with other grant award information. Members of the public may conduct searches using a variety of fields and/or keywords, and view or download the results. For more information on the DoD grant award data available from this website, please see the frequently asked questions (FAQ) section under the Help menu."

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to review the following two **databases** (other sources might be available as well):

- [Federal grants, affiliated with US Department of Defense (DoD)](http://www.grants.gov/search-grants.html?agencies%3DDOD|Department%20of%20Defense) (I see only *posted* and *closed* grant opportunities, but couldn't find how to get the *funded* ones - see the other source below.)
- [USA Spending Map](https://www.usaspending.gov/transparency/Pages/SpendingMap.aspx) (Here you definitely can get **funded** grant opportunities - just select Agency: DoD, Award Type: Grants, Fiscal Year and other parameters, if any. This database is also nice, because it offers options to either download data sets, or use its RESTful APIs.)

P.S. Should you become interested in DoD *contracts*, that information is available [on their website](http://www.defense.gov/News/Contracts).

Comment: The middle link is broken but here it is in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160404174019/https://www.usaspending.gov/transparency/Pages/SpendingMap.aspx