# Information on Grants & Funding in mathematical research

Tags: funding, united-states, canada

Professors of mathematics in research universities get grants and funding from time to time. I have two questions regarding this issue:

1) There are many sources of grants and funding, are there any ways to search the records of grants & funding a person got? (Of course I know I can ask that person or I may consult the records of each single sources, but I just want to know is there a more convenient way to do that.)

2) What are the most common grants and funding math professors get? **(I am not shopping among those sources, which sources are most commonly gotten in this field has statistical and objective answer)**

I am asking about the information in United States and Canada.

Comment: You can find links to NSF and DoD award search sites here: [Database of funded US Department of Defense (DoD) component grant proposals with abstracts: Does it exist?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/62163)

Comment: NSERC had public database of all award holders: http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca/ase-oro/index_eng.asp

Comment: You are asking two different questions. Usually it's best to ask them in two separate... questions.